# Controlar caracteres en campo js-grid

Tags: javascript

requiero poder controlar que en un campo del grid no permitan ingresar caracteres como `!@"#$%&/()`

ya modifique la funcion de esta forma utilizando la opción RegEXp

```
$str_eventUpdating=',onItemUpdating: function(args)
                {   
                      var grupo_promocion;
                      var c_barra;
                      var pattern =  new RegExp(/^[^!@"#$%&\/()]*$/);

                      c_barra=args.item.c_barra;
                      grupo_promocion=args.item.grupo_promocion;

                    if (args.item.grupo_promocion === null || args.item.grupo_promocion == "" ) {
                        grupo_promocion="";
                    }   

                    if(pattern.test(document.getElementById("grupo_promocion"))){
                          alert("No se permite ingresar caracteres como @ # & %")
                          args.cancel = true;
                    }else{
                           updategpromocion(c_barra,args.item.grupo_promocion); 
                          alert("Se actualizo el grupo de promoción correctamente")
                    }

                }

          ';
```

pero me sigue apareciendo el control si ingreso numero y letras normal

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de la función de `onItemEditing`, te recomiendo usar [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) para controlar los caracteres que contiene:

Con la expresion `^[^!@"#$%&\/()]*$` indico que no puede contener los caracteres que tú especificas.  (ten en cuenta que el `/` ha de escaparse y por eso puse `\/`)

Dentro de tu funcion `onItemEditing` has de meter lo que contiene mi funcion `comprobar()` y en vez de cambiar un texto `p` puedes poner `alerts` como tenias o lo que veas.

```js
function comprobar(){

    var pattern =  new RegExp(/^[^!@"#$%&\/()]*$/);

   
    if(pattern.test(document.getElementById("prueba").value)){
   
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "correcto";
        return true;
    }else{
   
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "incorrecto";
        return false;
   
    }
 
 
}

$('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    comprobar();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  id="prueba"> 



<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Comment: Hola tengo una duda, en mi caso no  tengo un input  separado donde ingreso el dato del grupo de promoción. este campo esta dentro del grid. este se identifica por el item.grupo_promocion. en este caso como puedo aplicar tu solución, sin tener que crear un input separado para poderle relaciónar la funcion comprobar

Comment: esta forma teniendo en cuenta la funcion indicada ,onItemUpdating: function(args) { var grupo_promocion;
   var c_barra;
   var pattern =  new RegExp(/^[^!@"#$%&\/()]*$/);

   c_barra=args.item.c_barra;
   grupo_promocion=args.item.grupo_promocion;
if (args.item.grupo_promocion === null || args.item.grupo_promocion == "" ) {grupo_promocion="";}
  if(pattern.test(grupo_promocion).value){
  args.cancel = true;
  alert("No se permite ingresar caracteres!")
   }else{updategpromocion(c_barra,args.item.grupo_promocion); 
 alert("Se actualizo el grupo de promoción correctamente")
}
}